# R: How to add documentation in R workspace image

Tags: r, image, attributes, workspace, rdata

I have saved my workspace as R data with required variables to be shared with my colleagues. I was wondering if there is a way to add documentation or additional information such as basic variable descriptions, data author etc. with Rdata.
I can add additional information to dataframes by adding attributes by using attr(). I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this for the entire R workspace.

Comment: rawr! i am working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save text that describes everything as an object in the .RData file

```
README <- scan("text_that_describes_everything.txt",sep="\n",what="character")
```